# FMOD Result not being recognized as a valid type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, fmod

I have following block of code copied almost verbatim out of the fmod tutorials, with a minor modification of variable names so as not to conflict with anything. My code compiles fine without any of the fmod statements. When I put the `FMOD_RESULT fm_result` line and all that follows I get an error stating `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int` I have VS2010, there are no linker or include file errors without the fmod code. The error is regarding the line `fm_result = FMOD::System_Create(&fm_system);` I also get the error `error C2371: 'fm_result' : redefinition; different basic types` on the same line.

```
FMOD_RESULT fm_result;
FMOD::System *fm_system;
fm_result = FMOD::System_Create(&fm_system);        // Create the main system object.

if(fm_result != FMOD_OK){
    printf("FMOD error! (%d) %s\n", fm_result, FMOD_ErrorString(fm_result));
    exit(-1);
}
fm_result = fm_system->init(100, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);  // Initialize FMOD.
if(fm_result != FMOD_OK){
    printf("FMOD error! (%d) %s\n", fm_result, FMOD_ErrorString(fm_result));
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a namespace perchance? Looks like some things are in the `FMOD` namespace, why not the result type?

Comment: I'm not sure why they do that, this is copied directly from the documentation, FMOD has no member FMOD_RESULT

Comment: Same situation, FMOD has no member RESULT :/

Comment: Stupid question: Are you #including `fmod.hpp`?

Comment: Yes I was. I decided to use directshow for audio since it was a  relatively trivial component to what I was doing, I might go back and replace it with fmod if I can get it working later. I'm not entirely sure what the problem was though similar issues occurred when I made a new project, I might try using the c interface instead and see how that works, thanks for your help!

Comment: http://google.com.au/codesearch#ildjMKPyYrY/trunk/CCV-COT/libs/fmodex/include/fmod.h&q=FMOD_RESULT&type=cs&l=258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, it must be something about Visual Studio, or something else you're not telling us... The following compiles fine with me in GCC 4.6:

```
#include <fmod.hpp>
#include <fmod_errors.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  FMOD_RESULT fm_result;
  FMOD::System *fm_system;
  fm_result = FMOD::System_Create(&fm_system);        // Create the main system object.

  if(fm_result != FMOD_OK)
  {
    printf("FMOD error! (%d) %s\n", fm_result, FMOD_ErrorString(fm_result));
    exit(-1);
  }

  fm_result = fm_system->init(100, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);  // Initialize FMOD.

  if(fm_result != FMOD_OK)
  {
    printf("FMOD error! (%d) %s\n", fm_result, FMOD_ErrorString(fm_result));
    exit(-1);
  }
}
```

I extracted `fmodapi43405linux.tar.gz` into `/tmp/` and invoked the compiler like this:

```
g++ -W -Wall -Wextra -s -O3 -march=native -o prog prog.cpp \
    -I /tmp/fmodapi43405linux/api/inc/ \
    /tmp/fmodapi43405linux/api/lib/libfmodex.so
```

It also works if I append `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: not sure what it was but I switched back to trying to use fmod this morning and it worked, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error:
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

You would get this if you put FMOD_RESULT blah before your first include of FMOD. Can you make sure that is not the case? Perhaps you have an include chain that is using FMOD_RESULT before including fmod.h.

Comment: This is not the issue, I only use it in one file and it is definitely after it is included.